# python one line save values of lists in dict to list

Tags: python

I would like to write for loop in one line:

```
d = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [5, 6, 7], 'c': [9, 0]}

my_list = []
for k, v in d.items():
    for x in v:
        my_list.append(x)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Not related to the question, but note that `list` and `dict` are really bad variable names, as they're both inbuilt constructors for `[]` and `{}` respectively.

Comment: @Yuushi oops yep, I was gonna mention that too but forgot. I'll just edit them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> d = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [5, 6, 7], 'c': [9, 0]}
>>> [y for x in d.values() for y in x]
[1, 2, 3, 9, 0, 5, 6, 7]
```

This is a nested [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). To show how this works, you can break it up into lines to see it's structure as nested `for` loops. It goes from left to right.

```
[y 
 for x in d.values() 
 for y in x]
```

Comment: How can I understand how to use double for loop like this? I don't get what is what xD

Comment: @bandit I edited the answer to show how it works. It's a list comprehension in case you didn't know

Comment: @jamylak I know it's list comprehension
I just tought I should use something like:
[x for x in v for v in d.values()].
Now I understand how to write it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
list(itertools.chain(*d.values()))
```

As @jamylak suggested, the following can be more efficient, as it avoids the full-unpacking done by the `*` operator:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
```

In python 2.x, use `.itervalues` instead of `.values`, to avoid unnecessary copying of lists.

Comment: you mean `chain.from_iterable`

Comment: @jamylak, yes my answer didn't quite worked. I fixed it by adding `*`

Comment: That's practically equivalent, except you have to unpack all the values first, `chain.from_iterable` should be more efficient

Comment: @jamylak, thanks. I added your suggestion to the question (although the OP didn't mention speed as a priority)

Comment: Ok you have my +1, This might be the fastest way for huge lists since it since it keeps everything at the `C` level, only calling functions implemented in `C` which makes it much faster, avoiding the overhead of Python, however in most practical situations mine would be faster I think

Comment: You could add the information that the method `itervalues` is removed in Python3 and to use `iter(d.values())` instead in this case.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
ll = []
for l in d.values(): 
    ll.extend(u)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using operator overloading -

```
sum(d.values(), [])
```

Comment: BEWARE: This has `O(N^2)` runtime. Also doesn't work as is in Py3k